# Intento crear una lista y mostrarla en el layout pero no para de tirar el error Unresolved reference: Person

Tags: android, kotlin

Estoy intentando de mostrar el contenido de de una lista en un layout (el codigo aun no está terminado) pero a la hora de tratar de llenar la lista no me reconoce la referencia del data class modelo que creé. les dejo el codigo

No se si lo tengan que tener el cuenta pero en la aplicacion tengo varios Activity en los que estoy practicando los conceptos basicos de Kotlin (Click events, Extension functions, Intents, Kotlin Android Extensions, Life Cycles, List Views, Permissions Shared References y tambien tengo la libreria Picasso alli y varios activity implementando funciones de Picasso)

```kotlin
package com.gabrielmilito.appclass.activities

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.gabrielmilito.appclass.R
import com.gabrielmilito.appclass.activities.models.Person


class ListViewActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_view)
    }

    private fun getPersons():List<Person> {
        val listOfPeople:List<Person> = listOf (
            Person("Gabriel","Milito", 20)
                    Person("Alejandro", "Lora", 27) // Unresolved Reference
            Person("Armando", "Casas", 34)
            Person("Roberto", "Sanchez", 23)
            Person("Alicia","Vega",37)
            Person("Dagoberto","Castillo",56)
            Person("Camila","Fernandez",19)
            Person("Antonio","Garita",15)
            Person("Valeria","Galante",21)
            Person(firstName = "Valentino", lastName = "Hernandez", age = 31)
            Person("Alejandro", "Lora", 27)
        )
        return listOfPeople
        }
}
```

[image: Imagen de referencia]
y aqui está el data class

```
data class Person(val firstName: String, val lastName:String, val age:Int)
```

y esto es lo que me dice android studio

```
> Task :app:compileDebugKotlin FAILED
e: C:\Users\gabri\AndroidStudioProjects\AppClass\app\src\main\java\com\gabrielmilito\appclass\activities\ListViewActivity.kt: (18, 39): Expecting ')'
e: C:\Users\gabri\AndroidStudioProjects\AppClass\app\src\main\java\com\gabrielmilito\appclass\activities\ListViewActivity.kt: (28, 9): Expecting an element
e: C:\Users\gabri\AndroidStudioProjects\AppClass\app\src\main\java\com\gabrielmilito\appclass\activities\ListViewActivity.kt: (18, 21): Unresolved reference: Person

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Compilation error. See log for more details
```

Gradle

```kotlin
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.gabrielmilito.appclass"
        minSdkVersion 27
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:30.0.0'
}
```

Realmente no sé que hacer, soy un novato en todo esto, si me ayudan les estare muy agradecidos

Clean/Rebuild no me funcionaron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes separar tus instancias con comas

```
private fun getPersons():List<Person> {
        val listOfPeople:List<Person> = listOf (
                Person("Gabriel","Milito", 20),
                Person("Alejandro", "Lora", 27), 
                Person("Armando", "Casas", 34),
                Person("Roberto", "Sanchez", 23),
                Person("Alicia","Vega",37),
                Person("Dagoberto","Castillo",56),
                Person("Camila","Fernandez",19),
                Person("Antonio","Garita",15),
                Person("Valeria","Galante",21),
                Person(firstName = "Valentino", lastName = "Hernandez", age = 31),
                Person("Alejandro", "Lora", 27)
        )
        return listOfPeople
    }
```